# Get a category in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I have this kind of categories in magenta:

> -MotoCross
>             ->Parts1 ->sub-parts
>             ->Parts2 ->sub-parts
>             ->Parts3 ->sub-parts
>
> -Quad
>             ->Parts1 ->sub-parts
>             ->Parts2 ->sub-parts
>             ->Parts3 ->sub-parts

For now i have MotoCross and Quad printed on screen and their child (parts1,2,3) but I would like to have Part1 and them sub parts printed on screen. 
I don't know how to do, see my code bellow:

---------------------------EDIT---------------------------
Now I have the current category categories, but i don't know how two have current category categories *categories*. You're still here ? :P

```
    <?php
    $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $actualCategoryId = $object->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    $actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($actualCategoryId);
    $subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());
?>
<div id="categories_list">
    <ol>
    <?php
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
        if ( $category->getIsActive() )
        { ?>
            <li class="second_level_cat">
            <?php
            echo '<a href="'.$category->getURL().'">'.$category->getName().'</a> ';
            ?>
            </li>
            <?php

        }
    }
?>
</ol>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code

```
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2)->getAllChildren(); // 2 = Root Category
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
```

Select Category :

```
<select id="_cid" name="_cid">
    <?PHP foreach ($catIds as $cid){ ?>
        <?PHP  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cid); ?>

        <?PHP if($_category->getLevel() == 3 ) { ?>
            <option value="<?PHP echo $_category->getId() ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $_category->getName() ?></option>
        <?PHP } ?>

        <?PHP if($_category->getLevel() == 4 ) { ?>
            <option value="<?PHP echo $_category->getId() ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?PHP echo $_category->getName() ?></option>
        <?PHP } ?>

    <?PHP } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Not exactly.. see, on left side: http://www.klgracing.com/motocross-enduro/equipement-pilote-motocross.html

Answer (score 1):

It's something like this.

```
<div id="categories_list">
    <ol>
    <?PHP foreach ($catIds as $cid): ?>
        <?PHP  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cid); ?>
        <?PHP if($_category->getLevel() == 2 ) : ?>
        <li class="second_level_cat">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
        </li>

        <?php
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()); 
            $childrens = $cat->getChildren(); 

            if($childrens) 
            {
                $childs=explode(",",$childrens);
                foreach($childs as $child){
                    $cat_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child);
                ?>
                        <li class="third_level_cat">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($cat_child) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($cat_child)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo ucfirst(strtolower($this->htmlEscape($cat_child->getName()))) ?></a>
                        </li>
                <?php
                } 
            }
        ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```